# How to shuffle a list, so that every sublist of a specific length has unique items?

Tags: python, python-3.x, algorithm, sorting, shuffle

Given: A randomly shuffled ID-list of unique utterances and a list of the speakers, to which the individual utterances belong (in the same order)

Problem: 
How to reorder the uttIDList, so that every sublist with 32 elements, starting from the first element with stepsize 32 holds utterances from different speakers?
It is important, that if we rerun the algorithm on different shuffled lists, we also get different sublists.

For example:

```
uttIDList = [1, 0, 9, 7, 100, 2, 3, 8301, ...] (length dividable by 32)

spkIDList = [0, 0, 3, 2, 1, 4, 20, 4, ...] 

sublist0 = uttIDList[0:32]

sublist1 = uttIDList[32:64]

...

sublistN = uttIDList[N-32,N]
```

Comment: Will each id in `spkIDList` be repeated the same number of times?

Comment: Why is the original shuffled list significant?  Is there some requirement to preserve that original shuffled order as best we can?  What have you tried so far?  This appears to be a straightforward problem: choose 32 utterances; de-dup speakers and replace with new choices.  Repeat until  the speaker list is unique.  Adjust at the last few sublists for speakers that haven't been chosen enough.

Comment: @brandon No sadly not.  My guess is, there might not be a solution for all cases, it is okey to cut off a portion from the uttIDList to make it work

Comment: Right -- if some speaker has given us more utterances than we have sublists, then no solution exists.  Please clarify the full problem and show your attack so far.

Comment: @please clarify exactly what you mean by "holds utterances from different speakers"

Comment: Does the order of speakers in the sublists matter?

Comment: @Prune I adjusted the question, the original shuffling isn't important, it is just important that given different shuffled lists we also get different sublists.

Comment: @brandon No it doesn't

Comment: @Jinglesting Every resulting sublists has 32 utterances, that must be from different speakers.

Comment: When you reach a resolution, please remember to up-vote useful answers and accept teh best (even if you have to write it yourself).  This allows Stack Overflow to archive your question.

Answer (score 2):

Ignore the original ordering entirely.  Make a reference list (e.g. dict) of the speakers and utterances.  Rotate the problem a quarter-turn: you're going to start from scratch, distributing the utterances from each speaker among the sublists.

- Initialize `k` lists to empty, where `k = N/32`
- Check your dict of utterances: if any speaker has more than `k` utterances, delete the excess.
- Sort a list of speakers in descending order of quantity of utterances; this will help avoid end-game problems.
- Repeat the following for each speaker:

  - List all sublists that are not yet full (i.e. len(sublist) < 32)
  - Let i = len(speaker's utterances list)
  - Take a random sample of the unfilled sublists, size `i`, using `random.sample`
  - append the speaker's utterances to the chosen lists.

This will work for most cases; it's possible to end up with a sublist having 2 open slots and the final speaker having 2 utterances to place.  In Real Life, a simple swap will fix the aberration.

Does that get you going?

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this definitely helps

Answer (score 2):

This should do it.

```py
# first map the id of each speak to a list of the indices that correspond to the speaker
spk_indices_map = {}
for i, spk_id in enumerate(spkIDList):
    if spk_id not in spk_indices_map:
        spk_indices_map[spk_id] = []
    spk_indices_map[spk_id].append(i)

# next shuffle the order of the indices for each speaker
# this still preserves which indices correspond to each speaker
for spk_id in spk_indices_map:
    shuffle(spk_indices_map[spk_id])

# the shuffled utterance and speaker lists with the desired properties
shuffled_uttIDList = []
shuffled_spkIDList = []

done = False
while not done:
    # while every speaker has at least one utterance not in the shuffled lists
    for spk_id in spk_indices_map:
        # add an utterance from each speaker to the shuffled lists
        if not spk_indices_map[spk_id]:
            done = True
            break
        else:
            index = spk_indices_map[spk_id].pop()
            shuffled_uttIDList.append(uttIDList[index])
            shuffled_spkIDList.append(spkIDList[index])

print(shuffled_uttIDList)
print(shuffled_spkIDList)
```

We keep track of all the indices of the utterances corresponding to each speaker. Then for each speaker, we shuffle the order of their indices. For each speaker in order, we take an utterance from the shuffled index list.

If not every speaker has the same number of utterances, the final sublist in the shuffled lists will be smaller than the desired size and can be ignored.